# git status hangs even if `git gc` has been done

Tags: git, github

Before having this problem, I moved my pack files from a local repo to an HPC cluster. I later decide to move the whole repo to HPC. However, after transferring the files and making sure that all the files were in the right place in the repo, I found that `git status` never ended whenever I executed it. I've tried `git fsck` and then `git gc --prune=now`, but the same situation happened. I later tried `git gc` again (without any flag), but it still did not solve the problem.

Interestingly, when I tried `git status` in my local repo where the pack files had been removed, the command responded without any delay.

I'm wondering what might cause this issue and how I could potentially solve it. Thanks!

Comment: In case you do not have any unstaged and uncommitted changes, how about deleting '.git' (hidden, by default) folder in your repo source, and starting afresh with `git init`, and setting upstream to start afresh with git CLI.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was actually considering the same thing, but I'm wondering if I delete `.git` and then do `git init`, will I lose all my previous commits? Is anything going to be different before I do that? I do not have any unstaged and uncommitted changes. 

Previously when I tried to clean up my repository, I was wondering if it is okay to delete pack files if I'm sure that I'm not going to retrieve any files from the history in the future.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by HPC cluster... If it's on a network drive then git can't rely on the local notifications to detect changed files and needs to scan the whole drive every time you do anything.